# manage_pages and publish_pages permission issue on posting post on page in facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using this facebook api

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/feed
```

and I got this error.

```
"message": "(#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 200,
"fbtrace_id": "EHBzoSb+sr1"
```

Comment: what´s not clear about the error message? where do you want to post to? user profile? page? group? please be more specific on stackoverflow.

Comment: I want to post on page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to post to a page, according to the comments: You have to use a Page Token with the `publish_pages` permission in order to post to a Page. Right now you are probably trying to do the call with a User Token. `/me` would be the User then.

Comment: Thanks lushchn, I have also tried with page id but I don't know how to pass manage_pages and publish_pages permission to page.

Comment: those are permissions you need to accept in your login flow. then you get a user token, with the user token you get a page token. that´s quite broad though, you should take a look at the docs about that.